# about xslt count()

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to simply have a textual output that shows the song title and the number of the weeks that ranked #1. But, I don't know how to use count in xslt. Can anyone help me find out what's wrong with my code? The codes I have right now doesn't have any output.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />  
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="popular-recordings-dataset/recording">
    <xsl:sort select="count(//rank[. = '1'])" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(title, ' / ', count(//rank[. = '1']),'&#xA;')" />
    </xsl:for-each>    
</xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you post some sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="recording">
    <xsl:sort select="count(week/rank[. = 1])"
         data-type="number" order="descending"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="recording">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat(title, ' / ', count(week/rank[. = 1]), '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (none provided in the question !!!):

```
<popular-recordings-dataset>
  <recording>
   <title>Song1</title>
   <week no="23">
    <rank>1</rank>
   </week>
   <week no="24">
    <rank>2</rank>
   </week>
  </recording>
  <recording>
   <title>Song2</title>
   <week no="22">
    <rank>1</rank>
   </week>
   <week no="24">
    <rank>1</rank>
   </week>
   <week no="25">
    <rank>1</rank>
   </week>
  </recording>
  <recording>
   <title>Song3</title>
   <week no="21">
    <rank>1</rank>
   </week>
   <week no="26">
    <rank>1</rank>
   </week>
  </recording>
</popular-recordings-dataset>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
Song2 / 3
Song3 / 2
Song1 / 1
```

**Explanation**: The problem with your code is in using this expression:

```
count(//rank[. = '1'])
```

The argument to `count()` is an *absolute* XPath expression (starts with `/`), therefore it selects all `rank` elements in the document with value equal to `1`. This means that this expression doesn't depend on and vary with the current `rank` element and remains the same for all `rank` elements. Sorting on a constant doesn't change the initial ordering of the node-set -- as you have witnessed.

**Solution**:

**Change**:

```
count(//rank[. = '1'])
```

**to**:

```
count(.//rank[. = '1'])
```

But better, if the structure of the XML document is known in advance, then try to avoid using the `//` pseudo-operator, which can be very inefficient.